# Regression with statsmodels having index disaligned Series

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I have done some research to use regression in python and I found some problem this is my code i Hope you Can help me guys

[image]

[image]

I Have 2 variable when I use my code :

```
X = sm.add_constant(X)
result = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
```

I got this error : ValueError: The indices for endog and exog are not aligned
And len of X and Y are the sam 5486 if someone can help me it will be very kindfull thank u

Comment: *I can't do regression* is not a question.

Comment: Yes, that's a too generic request for help. I suggest you change it to something such as "regression with statsmodels having index disaligned Series"

Comment: Thank you @LucaMassaron

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't seem to have any problem. The problem is with your variables and their indices which are not aligned (they are somehow different in some way).

Since you are working with two Pandas Series that you are expecting being aligned, you can just extract their values and ignore about the indices.

Please try:

```
X = sm.add_constant(X.values)
result = sm.OLS(Y.values, X).fit()
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer , and If i want use regression and I have 2 dataframe I can do the same code that you share or should I do something else?Sh

Comment: Yes, definitevely. Have a look at: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html OLS takes array like inputs for dependent and independent variables. Also in a Pandas dataframe, if you use the .values method, this will turn the input into a Numpy array, and you won't suffer from any index disallineagment.